# How to add google translate in android app?

Tags: android

I am using Google Translate API but it is not working. I have created an app and enabled the translate API in Google Developer Console and created an android key to use it. When I call the translate execute method it gives an error in ip or android key.

Please give me some steps to use google translate api in an Android application.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2

There is a library download and follow instructions on the website